# Turtlebot unable to check laptop battery/BAT0/state

Tags: ros, battery

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ros version is Fuerte. Turtlebot unable to check laptop battery/BAT0/state.
I think there is laptop battery information at battery/BAT1/state. How can I change it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67616/turtlebot-unable-to-check-laptop-battery/bat0/state/) by [FourTrees](https://answers.ros.org/users/5449/fourtrees/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2013-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you start it? The launch file in turtlebot_bringup has this path parametrized, so you can just pass another one in.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FourTrees](https://answers.ros.org/users/5449/fourtrees/) on 2013-07-28**:
thank you ^^